# Two objects constructed when assigning to a map

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to store objects in my map but apparently when I try to assign a new one, they are constructed twice and one is destructed immediately.
Is there a way I can create local objects in an map or do I have to store pointers?

```
std::map<std::wstring,Bitmap> bitmaps;
void loadBitmaps(){
    for(auto f: listdir("bitmaps")) {
        std::wcout << "loading: " << f << std::endl;
        bitmaps[f] = Bitmap(f);
        std::wcout << "loaded\n";
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
loading: bitmap1.bmp
created with file constructor
created with empty constructor
destructed (the one with the file constructor)
loaded
```

Comment: You want to implement a move assignment operator.

Comment: This is not an array, btw. Under the hood, it's typically a tree, rather. Also, an approach that complements the move assignment operator is the use of `map::emplace()`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is not using an array, it is using a `std::map`. `std::map::operator[]` default constructs an object if there isn't already one at that key. To construct the object in place, use [`std::map::emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace).

```
bitmaps.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, f, f);
```

Comment: I'm not sure why but I'm getting this error:  **'const std::piecewise_construct_t' is not derived from 'const std::pair<_T1, _T2>'** among others

Comment: I have checked and this problem is solved by adding **std::forward_as_tuple(f)** to the key and value

Answer (score 2):

At first, the `map` is empty. When you call `bitmaps[f]`, an entry for the key `f` is created together with a default-constructed value. This is the `empty constructor` that you are seeing. So in this case:

1. A (temporary) instance of Bitmap is constructed via `Bitmap(f)`
2. A default constructed Bitmap is constructed via `bitmaps[f]`
3. The temporary Bitmap is assigned to the default-constructed one via `Bitmap & Bitmap::operator=(Bitmap &&)` or `Bitmap & Bitmap::operator=(Bitmap &&)`, depending on the implementation of Bitmap.

I recommend using `bitmaps.emplace(f, f)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

std::map operator[] (key)` is special:

- If the key is existing, a reference to the mapped value is returned.
- Otherwise a new pair with a default constructed mapped type is inserted and the reference to the new mapped value is returned.

Other standard containers do not have this behavior.

You observe the inserting of a new default constructed mapped value, but miss the assignment in your logging output (analyze the operator = (...), too).